# How can I write a program to insert, update, delete in struts using only one action class and without using dispatch action or lookup dispatch action?

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts

How can I write a program to insert, update, delete in struts using only one action class and without using dispatch action or lookupdispatch action? Is it possible to do so? According to [dZone](http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/struts/struts-example/struts-lookup-dispatch-action-example-1.html),

> LookupDispatchAction provides a mechanism for grouping a set of related functions into a single action, thus eliminating the need to create seperate actions for each functions.

However, I don't want to use it. Is it possible using only one action class? How can it be achieved? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It can be possible with **javascript**. just you should **setparameter** for **add**, **update** & **delete** & at action class you should get these parameter by(**request.getParameter("id")**) if you get add parameter then called add function otherwise **update** or **delete**.